# How to access instantiated objects from another class?

Tags: c#

I want to terminate the thread thr1 in Program Class from another class, 
I created a PoC code as shown below to demonstrate it better.
Assume my Program class is as below:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static Thread thr1;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thr1= new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));
            thr1.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Test.Exec();

        }
    }
```

and this is my Test class:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Exec()
    {
        Program.thr1.Abort();
        Program.thr1= new System.Threading.Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1, param2));
        Program.thr1.Start();
    }
}
```

What I actually want to do is to terminate the thr1 in class Program by the Exec method in Test class and reassign with different parameters and start it again. 
Is this possible?

**EDITED:** 
Maybe I should have asked how to access instantiated object from another class?

Comment: You would need to reference that class in some way.

Comment: I thought i referenced already, what is a example of it? could you please write me a short code please

Comment: I know you are asking for terminating a thread, but are you sure that is what you need? I am asking as it is generally better to pass something like a CancellationToken and abort when it is triggered.

Comment: @Mirko, I want to cancel the thread, and start it with different parameters all from another class, do you have any better idea?

Comment: @EmilyWong, I guess your problem isnt threading you want to kknow how to reference your thread in other classes, aint it?

Comment: @EmilyWong my comment is about you being in control of the thread you are spawning. If you are and can change it's code, then I think you are best off passing a CancellationToken and respawning a new thread after it stops (but controlled, not aborted). I will post an answer with some simplistic sample code to show what I am getting at.

Comment: @hessamhedieh, initially it was threading as well, but for now I don't know how to reference the Thread in Program in another class.

Comment: `Terminate a thread from another class` short answer is you dont, long answer, is you let that thread end gracefully by writing code in that thread that allows it to end as such

Comment: Calling `.Abort()` on a thread should be **avoided at all costs** as this can cause the terminating thread to **corrupt the .NET run-time** and thus making **all other threads unreliable**. You should always write your code to allow threads to exit gracefully.

Comment: @Enigmativity, the above is just a POC. I will replace it with an die method in future.

Comment: @EmilyWong - What would the "die" method do?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I haven't code it yet, but it should stop the processing.

Comment: @EmilyWong - How would it stop the processing?

Comment: @Enigmativity, its not important, The problem is how to reference to the Program.thr1 from another class and be able to call its methods.

Comment: @EmilyWong, in your `Test.Exec` method, you have already refered to the `Program.th1` property. So what's your real problem?

Comment: @EmilyWong - Your solution should not call `.Abort()` - that's very important.

Comment: @shingo, the code doesnt work.. error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Enigmativity, This is just a POC code to find out how I can actually do it.

Comment: @EmilyWong - Your POC is the wrong way to do it. The only safe way to abort code is to run it in its own process and shut down the process.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Sure, I know that. I just want to know how to access an instance of thread object from another class? do you know how? please help if you know.

Comment: @EmilyWong - Yes, I do. Don't use `static` classes or methods. Instead create instances and pass references to them via their constructors. `static` classes and methods become very restrictive very quickly and make maintenance and testing extremely difficult.

Comment: @Enigmativity, but the thr1 is being started in Main, which is static. I cant solve this in this way..

Comment: Replace `Thread thr1= new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));` with `thr1 = new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));`. It should work as you've expected.

Comment: Solved Karan, Thanks!

Comment: `void Main` is creating a local variable `Thread thr1` instead of using the static `thr1` which is the one being accessed by other classes.

Answer (score 2):

Solution, @Karan Mentioned:

Replacing

`Thread thr1= new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));`

with

`thr1 = new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));`

It should work as you've expected.

**Edit**

It was not working because in code declaring `Thread thr1` inside `Main` which creating new local instance and not accessible to other classes.

As your global object is static it will always give you same reference. So assigning as `thr1 = new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As a general advice element avoid Thread Abort. It does not result in graceful shutdown and can lead to all kinds of issues. Most importantly make sure your thread is not responsible for keeping any relevant data intact. Thread.Abort will result in a ThreadAbortException being thrown and often does not result in what you would want to happen in all circumstances. If you do not control the code launched in the thread you may not have another option, but if you do, do not use this mechanism.

Consider using something like this. (Note the relevant part is you being able to gracefully terminate the work you are doing on the worker thread (sometimes this is difficult):

This is a C# 7.2 console app (as it has an async main method).

Just create this as a Console App to test, but if you do run it from an actual command line as VS sometimes doesn't play nice with CTRL-C interruption.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL-C to STOP!");
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => cts.Cancel();
        var longRunningTask = Task.Run(() => DoSomethingLongRunning(cts.Token));

        while (!longRunningTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            await Task.Delay(50, cts.Token);
        }
    }

    private static async Task DoSomethingLongRunning(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
            Console.WriteLine("Doing Something");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to do it from another Class, what you coded is not what exactly I need :(

Comment: @EmilyWong as long as you can pass the CancellationTokenSource or token you can cancel the task from anywhere. Let me update the sample. I was trying to make a point of not Abort()-ing threads if you can help it :)

Comment: My code is a bit complicated..., In my design, I can't pass token, I have CodeDom Compiler doing runtime compile and then the source which is inside runtime compile will abort the thread in Program and rerun the thread with new values.. so the Test.Exec is the one who start first without getting any value from Program class. If i know how to reference to the thr1 in the Program class from another Class, I have my answer.

Comment: @Mirko - You've written some nice code that is the correct way to handle this situation, but you do not address the OP's question. Can you include an opening paragraph on why the OP's approach isn't the correct way?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am not sure the OPs question isn't the right way. It generally isn't but I am not sure of her situation yet. I wish there was a better way to provide code/snippets for comments as consideration as my answer wasn't even really intended as an answer but a "consideration" :). Emily is saying she cannot pass a token which makes me think she is not in control of the code in the thread launched.

Comment: @Mirko - Excellent answer now that you have added the opening paragraph!

Comment: @Mirko, Thanks for both answers, yes I have no control of the Program class. the program class is launching the thread by itself with its own parameters, What I want to do is to access the Program class, call the shutdown method of the thread which is already started long time ago, assign the thread new values, and start it again.

Comment: @EmilyWong - You need to provide us with a [mcve] of what you want to do. But, based on what you just said I'd have to say it is impossible to start threads again. Once they are "shutdown" they die forever.

Comment: All this should be done externally from another class as I can't pass parameters such as Token from Program class to another class. I think if I know how to access the instance of the already running Thread in Program class, I can solve this problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I didnt say i want to rerun the already shutdown thread, I will assign it new values and .Start() it again.

Comment: @EmilyWong The code for the thread that is being launched, is it in your control (your = your org)?

Comment: @EmilyWong Then my comment applies you ought to pass a CancellationToken to make sure all work in it stops gracefully. Passing the token is simple and there are more ways than I can quickly call out. You ought to spell out how your Test and Program classes are related. Meaning what context do Program and Test share?

Comment: @EmilyWong - You say ".Start() it again" - which is why I read that as you're starting it again. You can't do that. You can only ever create a brand new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Program
{
    public static Thread thr1;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        thr1= new Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1,param2));
        thr1.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Test.Exec();

    }
}
```

Test class

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Exec()
    {
         Program.thr1.Abort();
         Program.thr1= new System.Threading.Thread(() => Class1.DoSomething(param1, param2));
        Program.thr1.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's showing another error: Member 'Program.thr1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

Comment: @preciousbetine, kindly, how did you manage to use `this` in `Main`?